# Prevent long lines getting wrapped in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I use the `load_yaml_guess_indent(f, preserve_quotes=True)` to read a YAML file, then modify it and write it back. I noticed long lines are getting wrapped when they are written back. (A line break is inserted after 80-85 characters.) Is there a parameter I can pass to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are the parameters you can hand in to `round_trip_dump()`:

```
def round_trip_dump(data, stream=None, Dumper=RoundTripDumper,
                default_style=None, default_flow_style=None,
                canonical=None, indent=None, width=None,
                allow_unicode=None, line_break=None,
                encoding=enc, explicit_start=None, explicit_end=None,
                version=None, tags=None, block_seq_indent=None,
                top_level_colon_align=None, prefix_colon=None):
```

The one you are looking for is `width`

If you are using the new (`ruamel.yaml >= 0.15` ) API, most of these parameters directly translate to attributes on the YAML instance you create, so in that case you would do:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.width = 4096  # or some other big enough value to prevent line-wrap
yaml.dump(data, stream=your_stream)
```

Comment: @KatrinaBrock Done

Comment: @JeffHykin That is because the line width (an integer) is compared to the value provided, and that value is not "cast" to an an integer. I.e. in Python  `80 < float("Infinity")` gives `True` but `int(float("Infinity"))` throws an overflow error.

Comment: Is it possible to preserve existing line wrapping regardless of width? Fixed line width causes either wrapping or unwrapping if existing line wrappings are inconsistent, and I'd like to reduce whitespace noise