# Preserve line wrapping in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Is there a way to preserve line wrapping with `ruamel.yaml`? The closest I have found is to use the `width` property but that doesn't quite do it.

[Prevent long lines getting wrapped in ruamel.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170709/prevent-long-lines-getting-wrapped-in-ruamel-yaml)

My use case: I have a yaml file with some long lines and some where they are already wrapped. To minimize changes when doing a round-trip update, I'd like the untouched lines to keep their wrapping.

```
import ruamel.yaml
import sys

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.width = 999

instr = """\
description: This is a long line that has been
  wrapped.
url: https://long-url.com/add-more-characters-so-that-it-goes-out-farther-than-the-default-80-cols
value: 7
"""

test = yaml.load(instr)

# Modify <value>
test['value'] += 1

yaml.dump(test, sys.stdout)
```

Output below. The `description` is unwrapped and `url` is moved to a new line.

```
description: This is a long line that has been wrapped.
url: 
  https://long-url.com/add-more-characters-so-that-it-goes-out-farther-than-the-default-80-cols
value: 8
```

If I uncomment the `yaml.width = 999` line the `url` looks the way I want, but `description` changes.

```
description: This is a long line that has been wrapped.
url: https://long-url.com/add-more-characters-so-that-it-goes-out-farther-than-the-default-80-cols
value: 8
```

What I really want is the `description` and `url` lines to match the original, only `value` changing:

```
description: This is a long line that has been
  wrapped.
url: https://long-url.com/add-more-characters-so-that-it-goes-out-farther-than-the-default-80-cols
value: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue here is that the yaml specification will always ignore newlines in flow scalars (ie. not block scalars).

From the [specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) (see Examples 2.17 and 2.18):

> All flow scalars can span multiple lines; line breaks are always folded.

Because line breaks are always folded with flow scalars, ruamel.yaml will ignore your newline in the `description:` field when the yaml string is *loaded*. Then when it comes time to dump the result, the information is already lost.

If you want yaml to preserve newlines in the output you need to use the block scalar format (see section 2.3 in the [specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/)).

If your initial yaml document looks like this instead (with block scalars):

```yaml
description: | 
  This is a long line that has been
  wrapped.
url: https://long-url.com/add-more-characters-so-that-it-goes-out-farther-than-the-default-80-cols
value: 7
```

Then the library will recognize the line break when it is loaded and so will preserve it when it is dumped later on.

**EDIT**

As @Anthon points out in their comment/answer using the `>-` syntax will get you a string that is closest to the one in your original document. See the specification links I've provided for more information on the difference between `|` and `>-`.

Comment: Using a literal scalar you get not only a newline at the end of the value for `description`, you also get one between `been` and `wrapped`. To facilitate better (but not perfect) round-trips `ruamel.yaml` doesn't follow the YAML specification and doesn't always drop/ignore what it says a parser should do. E.g in folded style it marks the position of where the lines are folded, to reinsert these on output.

Answer (score 0):

`ruamel.yaml` doesn't try to preserve "soft" newlines in plain or quoted scalars. It currently only tries to do so in block style folded scalars.

Since for the argument for key `url` you need to set the linelength to a large enough number otherwise the value will not fit the line and be pushed to the next line (where it also doesn't fit, but with 2 positions less sticking out, and yes the algorithm could be smarter). So there is no way to get what you want with your input.

What should be preserved on round-trip and have the same value for key `description` is the using the folded scalar.

```
description: >-
  This is a long line that has been
  wrapped.
url: https://long-url.com/add-more-characters-so-that-it-goes-out-farther-than-the-default-80-cols
value: 7
```